# SharePoint 2010 timer job: Execute method is not executed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've tried to execute my custom timer job by edit -> 'start now' but it seems like the method was not even called. It has the only instruction `Trace.Assert(false);` and a breakpoint on it. Journal says that it was executed correctly. I tried to restart SPTimerV4; It runs. Execution time of the job (and any other job) is 0:00. Could someone help me fix this?

Thank you,

Comment: Although it is not really an answer I would strongly suggest reviewing your ULS logs during and immediately after you start the timer job. It is most likely that your job is failing and is just not informing the timer service accordingly which can be due to a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug the timerjob by attaching to the owstimer.exe process using Visual Studio and set a breakpoint at the start of the execute method. From there it should be relatively easy to figure out what goes wrong.